# What is the bananafish? What does it represent?

Tags: symbolism, short-stories, j-d-salinger

In J.D. Salinger's *A Perfect Day For Bananafish*, Seymour, the main character, talks about a bananafish. He tells a little girl about the bananafish.  The little girl says she sees the fish.

What is the bananafish and what does it represent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The bananafish represents Seymour, and all the other returning soldiers.

> "Well, they swim into a hole where there's a lot of bananas. They're very ordinary-looking fish when they swim in. But once they get in, they behave like pigs. Why, I've known some bananafish to swim into a banana hole and eat as many as seventy-eight bananas." He edged the float and its passenger a foot closer to the horizon. "Naturally, after that they're so fat they can't get out of the hole again. Can't fit through the door."
>   ...
>   Sybil said, "What happens to them?"
>   "What happens to who?"
>   "The bananafish."
>   "Oh, you mean after they eat so many bananas they can't get out of the banana hole?"
>   "Yes," said Sybil.
>   "Well, I hate to tell you, Sybil. They die."
>   "Why?" asked Sybil.
>   "Well, they get banana fever. It's a terrible disease."

This represents Seymour pretty accurately.

- He and other soldiers came into war as ordinary men, like the bananafishes were ordinary when they went into the hole.
- In the hole (war), they became full of horror and/or pleasure at fighting, like the bananafishes eating the bananas and becoming full of.. well.. bananas.
- They became trapped inside the hole (war) and diseased. In the case of the soldiers, in more ways than one.  They became full of literal diseases, because the trenches are a nasty place, but they also became mentally ill.